# How to do Handshake with Firebase analytics?

Tags: android, events, google-analytics, firebase-analytics

I have successfully integrated Firebase Analytics SDk in my project.

I need to track all User actions. What user has performs during his sessions. Like screen navigation, button click etc.

Here is a one example to log event when user comes on Login screen.

`Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putString(FirebaseAnalytics.Param.ITEM_ID, uid);
bundle.putString(FirebaseAnalytics.Param.ITEM_NAME, "OPEN");
mFirebaseAnalytics.logEvent("open_login_screen", bundle);`

I can see the event logs on dashboard.

Queries:

1. Here In need to send uid each time at time of log event. Is there any way to send UID only one time and further events go under that UID?
2. Is there any way to filter data on "FirebaseAnalytics.Param.ITEM_NAME" parameter?

Answer (score 0):

You should consider user property User ID that will attach to every event after a user property is set by calling setUserID method
https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/analytics/FirebaseAnalytics.html#setUserId(java.lang.String)